# Is it considered wrong to have all server logic in one file?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm very new to node.js and socket.io (PHP dev) and I'm a little confused about how to setup my first project. In PHP for example, if I use Laravel, my backend is separated into many controllers and models. However, in node.js/socket.io, all the examples that I've been looking at seem to have everything in one file (usually server.js).

I feel like this can't be right and was just wondering if someone with experience could shed some light on the subject. Any explanations are much appreciated!

Comment: "Wrong" isn't the word i'd use to describe it. and whether or not it would be a maintenance problem would depend on the size of the application. An entire PHP application can be written in just one file too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just learned about modules and it seems to have answered my question.

Thanks anyways!